# How to create table using json in birt

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

i am having one column data as JSON format in table. i want to pass that column as report parameter in BIRT. can anyone help me how to parse JSON data and use it in the report.

Answer (score 0):

One way to access the data sent through report parameter is creating a POJO (Plain Old Java Objects) Data Source.
You should create 3 java classes and convert it to jar file and use that as input for POJO Data Source.
Make sure that column names in json file match with the properties you create in java class.
You can refer this video for more info:
["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZD8wog2pmk"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZD8wog2pmk)

Please let us know if you get other ways to achieve the same.